# How do you Merge Build and Artifacts from Multiple Projects in Gradle?

Tags: build, gradle, build-process, build-automation

How do you merge multiple project into one build.

Say I have project:

- ProjA
- ProjB
- ProjC

All have build.gradle but I want the build to be in the build directory of ProjA with all the output Jars and Doc Jars also merged in the build/lib directory.

The multiple projects are due to breaking up a larger project into smaller same level sub projects but we do not want to distribute multiple Jars for each sub project.

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand the question. do you just want the artifacts of your build in the projA/build folder? you can modify the buildDir property of a project ( build script) for that.

Comment: I want all the projects to be build in ProjA\buildDir with the single unified Jar and Doc outputs.